# How get the real query sent by python to sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code and I would like to get the real query sent by python.

```
pf = "try"  
cat = "man"  
sub_cat = "young" 

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `pf` = ? AND `cat` = ? AND `sub_cat` = ?", (pf, cat, sub_cat))
```

How could I do ?
The result I would like to get is :

```
SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `pf` = "try" AND `cat` = "man" AND `sub_cat` = "young"
```

Kind regards

Comment: That is the query.

Comment: But I would like to get something as 
SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `pf` = 'value' AND `cat` = 'value' AND `sub_cat` = 'value'

Comment: Do you think the parameters in the query are literally replaced by the values bound to them to make a new string that gets executed? It doesn't work that way.

Comment: It's not that simple, because the database engine never builds the "real" query that you want to retrieve. The parameterized version is the real query from its perspective (if anything if you send a query containing literal values the DB engine is likely doing extra work to parse them out and build a prepared statement). Most likely you'd have to do this yourself by manually replacing each `?` with the corresponding value, properly formatted in SQL syntax with correct quoting and escaping for strings, etc.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Actually the field sub_cat can be NULL

If i have in the database :  
try - man - NULL
try - man - young

SQL will return 1 result
pf = "try"  
cat = "man"  
sub_cat = "young" 

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `pf` = ? AND `cat` = ? AND `sub_cat` = ?", (pf, cat, sub_cat))

but if I have, the following no result are return
pf = "try"  
cat = "man"  
sub_cat = None 

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `pf` = ? AND `cat` = ? AND `sub_cat` = ?", (pf, cat, sub_cat))

Comment: Should I use a particular query like
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE pf = ? AND cat = ? AND sub_cat IS NULL", (pf, cat)